# How can I limit the size of the debug_kit.sqlite file in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The `debug_kit.sqlite` file in the tmp directory grows with every request by approx. 1.5 Mb. If I don`t remember to delete it, I am running out of disc space.

How could I limit it`s growth? I don't use the history panel, so I don't need the historic data. (Side question: why does it keep all historic requests anyways? In the history panel only the last 10 requests are shown, so why keep more than 10 requests in the db at all?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the debug_kit has a garbage collection. However it is not effective in reducing the disc space because sqlite needs to rebuild the database with the vacuum command to free disc space. I created a PR to implement vacuuming into the garbage collection: https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/pull/702

**UPDATE**: The PR has been accepted. You can solve the problem now by updating debug_kit to 3.20.3 (or higher): https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/releases/tag/3.20.3

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one main purpose for debug kit. DebugKit provides a debugging toolbar and enhanced debugging tools for CakePHP applications. It lets you quickly see configuration data, log messages, SQL queries, and timing data for your application. Simple answer is Just for debug. Even though only shown 10 requests, you can still query to get all histories such as

- Cache
- Environment
- History
- Include
- Log
- Packages
- Mail
- Request
- Session
- Sql Logs
- Timer
- Variables
- Deprecations

It's safe to delete `debug_kit.sqlite` or you can set false to generate again or what I did it I run cronjob to delete it every day.

Btw, you should not enable it for staging or production. Hope this help for you.

Comment: Writing a cron-job is a solution, but it is not really ideal. I would have to do this on every instance my app is running on.

Comment: I agree with you. My requirement is not really needed to store this debug_kit on production server. So, yes I run it locally and not painful to me at all.